# Collision Bounds Problem

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics

The Collision bounds are messed up on my character and I cant seem to fix it.  It is set to `Box`.  I tried Triangle Mesh but blender crashes (I looked it up and this is a regular bug) and none of the other Collision Bounds work.  So basically I need it to be `Box` and I need it to have Physics `Character`.  I've centered the origin to the middle but it just messes it up and the character goes flying.
[image: Collision Bounds]

Comment: Nevermind it is working now and I don't know why...

Comment: In your screenshot the origin is not in the middle. Try using Ctrl Shift Alt C > *Origin to Center of Mass*